# How to access a field inside a List or Array of JSON Object using SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following table

```
+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|company_name |                         products                                         |   
+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   comp1     | [{"name": "prod1","pending": false}, {"name": "prod2","pending": true}]  |
+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Suppose I want to retrieve results based on the the value of "name" field inside "products" column, for ex: if "pending" = "true", then display the company_name and also the product name of the particular JSON object inside the List or Array.

Result should look something like,

```
+-------------+-------------------------------+
|company_name |           product_name        |
+-------------+-------------------------------+
| comp1       |            prod2              | 
+-------------+-------------------------------+
```

Comment: MySQL version??

Comment: Your ask is somewhat trivial, because if `prod2` be both the search value and displayed value, then you are really just asking for an exists query.  Is there any other data you want returned?

Comment: Yes. Just for the sake of example I wrote prod2. I edited the example. Now my requirement is more clear. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Can you use json function (does `SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('{"foo":"bar"}', '$.foo')` work or throws an error)?

Comment: JSON_EXTRACT is working for a field which has a single JSON object. How do we traverse a field which has a List of JSON objects and access each Key inside the List? @SalmanA

Comment: @Mohammed you need to use `JSON_SEARCH` but seems like it cannot search for true/false.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a program in python, perl etc that retrieve json and convert it to array and you print the column of array that you need.

Comment: I am looking for an SQL query.

Comment: Which database system are you using ?

Comment: I am using MySQL

Answer (score 0):

use index to get value $[ index ]

Code will be like this:

```
Select company_name,json_extract(products,'$[1].name') product_name from table where json_extract(products,'$[1].pending')='false' ;
```

Note: create a dummy table with numbers and join it for index